# Read specific part of a text file and parsing in vb

Tags: vb.net

By reading a text file I have to create several comboxes and add items for those dynamically. Below is the my sample text file from where I have to parse 'Switch for DSO' string and then add a tab page for this. Tabpage name will be 'Switch'. Under this tab page, I have to create some comboboxes and add items for this boxes dynamically. For every combox boxes there will a label . Label name will be like 'Adhesive Type Switch' and on the right of the label a combo box will be added and items of the boxes will be 'Glue' and 'SoftSolder'. So under this 'Switches for DSO' tab page combo box will be created until it gets the string 'Options for DSO'. Can anybody give me a hints about this. It will be very helpful for me if you give me a hints with some code.

### Sample of text file:

//==================

// Switches for DSO-**Tab page1**

//==================

//Adhesive Type Switch-**Label of combobox1**

//#DEFINE Glue- **item of combobox1**

//#DEFINE SoftSolder- **item of combobox1**

// Application Switch-**Label of combobox2**

//#DEFINE Non-Automotive-**item of combobox2**

//#DEFINE Automotive-**item of combobox2**

// Bondpad Material and Process Switch of Chip Bottom-**Label of combobox3**

//#DEFINE Non_Passivated_ChipBottom-**item of combobox3**

//#DEFINE Copper_Bondpad_ChipBottom-**item of combobox3**

//#DEFINE Alu_Bondpad_Imide_ratio_ChipBottom-**item of combobox3**

//#DEFINE Alu_Bondpad_Imide_non_ratio_ChipBottom-**item of combobox3**

//==================

// Options for DSO-**Tab page2**

//==================

//Staggared Bondpad Arragement Option-**Label of checkbox1**

//#DEFINE STAGGERED-**checkbox1 value**

//Wedge on Bump Option-**Label of checkbox2**

//#DEFINE Wedge_on_Bump-**checkbox2 value**

// Chip Technology-**Label of checkbox3**

//#DEFINE SUPPLY1-**checkbox3 value**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many different tab layout you'll need, you could create the tab layout visually and then create instances as needed at runtime, adding them to the form (assuming WinForm).

Or you could have a generic tab (also reused) where you would instance and add the (templated) controls you need, setting their properties along the way.

You'll have to write a bunch of code to get what you want, parsing the file and building the tabx. You might also want to look at creating custom controls in .NET.